# Jquery toggle sometimes wont come out for 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a toggle jquery bug, with help from here, there are many bugs fixed but one bug stays.

When your mouse enters "meer informatie" then will a child div slide down. When you leave "meer informatie" before .panel has finished sliding down, then the next time you enter "meer informatie" it won't slide down for 100%

And i got a second question but i think i have to ask that in a new "ask question"

url of the staging page: http://staging.skyberate.nl/shared-hosting/magento-hosting/referenties/

I think it's a little bit like this problem, but don't really understand it:P
like this: [jquery toggle sometimes does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904442/jquery-toggle-sometimes-does-not-work)

jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".flip").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).find(".panel").stop().slideToggle("slow"); 
});
$(".flip").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).find(".panel").stop().slideToggle("slow");
});
}); 
</script>
```

css:

```
.flip{
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color:white;
 width:490px;
margin-left: 43px;
color:#1667b2;
text-align:center;
border-bottom: 2px solid #1667b2;
display:block;
}

.panel
{
width:480px;
color:white;
background-color:#1667b2;
float:left;
margin:0px;
display:none;
padding:5px;
}

#meerreferenties {
width:auto;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="flip"><p>Meer informatie</p>
<div class="panel"><p>Hier komt de informatie te staan over de desbetreffende hosting.
Hier komt de informatie te staan over de desbetreffende hosting.
Hier komt de informatie te staan over de desbetreffende hosting.
    Hier komt de informatie te staan over de desbetreffende hosting.
Hier komt de informatie te staan over de desbetreffende hosting.
Hier komt de informatie te staan over de desbetreffende hosting.
Hier komt de informatie te staan over de desbetreffende hosting.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to be a problem by itself...maybe it's conflicting with another script or another css rule...check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/9uJXc/

Comment: Yes that could be, my navbar doesnt work anymore, yes it does work, but not dropdown when i hover it. Is there a way to fix this? I'm using it in wordpress

Comment: I check the source of your site and you have two versions of jquery included

Comment: how can i fix this? somebody before me here at this company made this site so many things i dont know. And about jquery i know nothing:P

Comment: How to fix it.....mmm...maybe stop using wordpress, every plugin includes their own scripts or css styles, and wordpress is known for having several security issues...i check the source of your site and i know for sure that you dont need all those js and css files(dozens) to make your site works

Comment: I didn't made the whole site. The only thing i have to fix now i that the navbar works at the /referenties page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using an older version of jQuery (before 1.7) where the `stop()` function is not doing what you're expecting. [Here you can](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) read more about what jQuery says about the `stop()` function:

> **As of jQuery 1.7**, stopping a toggled animation prematurely with .stop() will trigger jQuery's internal effects tracking. In previous
>   versions, calling the .stop() method before a toggled animation was
>   completed would cause the animation to lose track of its state (if
>   jumpToEnd was false). Any subsequent animations would start at a new
>   "half-way" state, sometimes resulting in the element disappearing.

I can see two solutions for you:

1 - Update your jQuery version to 1.7 or newer.

2 - Call the stop function like this, with two true parameters: `.stop(true,true)`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flip").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find(".panel").stop(true,true).slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $(".flip").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find(".panel").stop(true,true).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PZA5c/14/) of this. The top information will be buggy while the bottom one will work. You can see that I'm using jQuery 1.6 here. If you switch to 1.7 both should work.

Comment: The animation gets stuck, after some times hovering over first one doesn't make it slide down.

Comment: @AmitJoki - That's exactly what I wanted to show. The first one doesn't use `stop(true,true)` so it won't work. The second one does pass in two true parameters and thus works.

Comment: But the first one still shows when hovered for the first time.

Comment: But you put in the code at the mouse enter 2 times true and at mouse leave 2 times true too

Comment: Lol, i deleted the the 2 true parameters at mouse enter and that works xD thanks guys!

Comment: @thommylue - The first parameter will clear the queue and the second parameter will finish the current animation.

Comment: Do you mean with the first .stop(true(first),true(second)) or do you mean the 2 actions leave and enter?

Comment: @thommylue - The first thing you said there: .stop(true(first),true(second)). Did you take a look at the documentation for the stop function that I linked?

Comment: Oh, no i should do this now. Can you help me with the fix for different jquery versions too? i would like to finish this today:P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48065/discussion-between-niklas-and-thommylue)